# Sitecore login fails when user clicks remember me

Tags: sitecore

I am trying to resolve an issue where users get a stack trace if they click "remember me" on the Sitecore login page.

I can only replicate the issue if I use an incorrect login.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

userName

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: userName

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: userName]
   Sitecore.Caching.UserProfile.UserProfileCache.RemoveUser(String userName) +223
   Sitecore.Caching.CacheManager.ClearSecurityCache(String userName) +32

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +76
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +211
   System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) +35
   Sitecore.Nexus.Pipelines.NexusPipelineApi.Resume(PipelineArgs args, Pipeline pipeline) +379
   Sitecore.Pipelines.Pipeline.Start(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, Boolean atomic) +197
   Sitecore.sitecore.login.LoginPage.Login_LoggingIn(Object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e) +`enter code here`377
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AttemptLogin() +79
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +93
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +84
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3804
```

Comment: what version of Sitecore are you using?

Comment: I get this error on sitecore version 7.1

Answer (score 3):

In new Sitecore versions, in order to improve the security of the login page, Sitecore recommends to disable the *Remember me* check box:

1. Open `sitecore.config` file
2. Set `Login.DisableRememberMe` setting to `true`

Note, that this also ignores any existing *Remember Me* cookies and all users will have to re-login again.

Read more details [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/increase-login-security.html).